Creating a custom VirtualizingLayout for Avalonia.ItemsRepeater
My overall goal is to have a grid layout with a variable number columns depending on a set of screen size breakpoints to display a list of controls. I.e., with a width of 720px, there would be 4 columns, with a width of 1024px there would be 5, etc..
From what I've found, this isn't necessarily natively supported with default Avalonia controls, so I've gone about creating my own layout class to use as a AttachedLayout to an ItemsRepeater, building on the idea of a UniformGridLayout.
I have the basics of the class down, and it works as I'd like with regards to layout, but am having some issues implementing virtualization. Without virtualization, the performance absolutely tanks as you'd expect, so this is a must have.
For reference, here is the class as I have it now
public class BreakpointColumnGridLayout : VirtualizingLayout
{
    public static readonly StyledProperty<List<(double width, int columns)>> BreakpointsProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<BreakpointColumnGridLayout, List<(double width, int columns)>>(nameof(Breakpoints), defaultValue: new List<(double width, int columns)>
        {
            (1058, 4),
            (1314, 5),
            (int.MaxValue, 6),
        });

    public static readonly StyledProperty<double> GutterSizeProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<BreakpointColumnGridLayout, double>(nameof(GutterSize), defaultValue: 10.0);

    public static readonly StyledProperty<bool> LimitToOneRowProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<BreakpointColumnGridLayout, bool>(nameof(LimitToOneRow), defaultValue: false);

    public bool LimitToOneRow
    {
        get => GetValue(LimitToOneRowProperty);
        set => SetValue(LimitToOneRowProperty, value);
    }

    public List<(double width, int columns)> Breakpoints
    {
        get => GetValue(BreakpointsProperty);
        set => SetValue(BreakpointsProperty, value);
    }

    public double GutterSize
    {
        get => GetValue(GutterSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(GutterSizeProperty, value);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(VirtualizingLayoutContext context, Size availableSize)
    {
        if (context.ItemCount <= 0 || Breakpoints == null || !Breakpoints.Any())
        {
            return new Size(0, 0);
        }

        var columns = DetermineColumns(availableSize.Width);
        var itemWidth = CalculateItemWidth(availableSize.Width, columns, GutterSize);
        itemWidth = Math.Max(itemWidth, 10);

        var itemCount = LimitToOneRow ? Math.Min(context.ItemCount, columns) : context.ItemCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            var child = context.GetOrCreateElementAt(i, ElementRealizationOptions.None);
            child.Measure(new Size(itemWidth, availableSize.Height));
        }

        var itemHeight = itemCount > 0 ? context.GetOrCreateElementAt(0).DesiredSize.Height : 0;
        var totalHeight = LimitToOneRow ? itemHeight : ((Math.Ceiling((double)itemCount / columns) * itemHeight) + ((Math.Ceiling((double)itemCount / columns) - 1) * GutterSize));

        totalHeight = Math.Max(totalHeight, 0);
        var totalWidth = Math.Max(availableSize.Width, 0);

        return new Size(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(VirtualizingLayoutContext context, Size finalSize)
    {
        if (context.ItemCount <= 0 || Breakpoints == null || !Breakpoints.Any())
        {
            return finalSize;
        }

        var columns = DetermineColumns(finalSize.Width);
        var itemWidth = CalculateItemWidth(finalSize.Width, columns, GutterSize);
        itemWidth = Math.Max(itemWidth, 10);

        var x = 0.0;
        var y = 0.0;
        var totalHeight = 0.0;
        var maxHeightInARow = 0.0;

        var itemCount = LimitToOneRow ? Math.Min(context.ItemCount, columns) : context.ItemCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            var child = context.GetOrCreateElementAt(i, ElementRealizationOptions.None);
            var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

            if (!LimitToOneRow && i % columns == 0 && i != 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                y += maxHeightInARow + GutterSize;
                totalHeight += maxHeightInARow + GutterSize;
                maxHeightInARow = 0;
            }

            child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, itemWidth, childSize.Height));
            x += itemWidth + GutterSize;
            maxHeightInARow = Math.Max(maxHeightInARow, childSize.Height);

            if (i == itemCount - 1 || LimitToOneRow)
            {
                totalHeight += maxHeightInARow;
            }
        }

        return new Size(finalSize.Width, totalHeight);
    }

    private int DetermineColumns(double containerWidth)
    {
        if (Breakpoints == null || !Breakpoints.Any())
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var sortedBreakpoints = Breakpoints.OrderBy(b => b.width).ToList();
        foreach (var breakpoint in sortedBreakpoints)
        {
            if (containerWidth <= breakpoint.width)
            {
                return breakpoint.columns;
            }
        }

        return sortedBreakpoints.Last().columns;
    }

    private double CalculateItemWidth(double containerWidth, int columns, double gutterSize)
    {
        if (columns <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var totalGutterWidth = (columns - 1) * gutterSize;
        var itemWidth = Math.Floor((containerWidth - totalGutterWidth) / columns);
        return itemWidth;
    }
}

The class inherits from VirtualizingLayout, but does not actually do any kind of virtualization. I've tried a few things with context.RealizationRect, but I don't think I have a full grasp on how it should be used in MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. I had something along the lines of this in ArrangeOverride:
if (x >= realizationBounds.Left && x <= realizationBounds.Right &&
                y >= realizationBounds.Top && y <= realizationBounds.Bottom)
            {
                child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, itemWidth, childSize.Height));
            }
            else if (y > realizationBounds.Bottom)
            {
                break;
            }

This had a set of issues:

It would did not render the last row correctly.
Fast strolling on large datasets would draw nothing at all until the user scrolled back to top.
It required the ItemsRepeater to need VerticalAlignment=Top, not sure on why that was.

I'm looking for a little help getting pointed in the right direction here.
